# Find the difference in time between two time values always gives the "Second" value as 0

Tags: java, android, time, simpledateformat

I'm trying to find the difference between current time value and a future time in HH:MM:SS format.

For example:
When date1 is "2017-05-11T20:30" and date2 is "2017-05-11T21:40", the output should be 01:10:00.

Here's the code I'm trying, wherein I'm trying to find the difference between current time and a future time value:

```
public void updateTimeRemaining() {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
    String currentTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    long difference = simpleDateFormat.parse(endTime).getTime() - simpleDateFormat.parse(currentTime).getTime();
    if (difference>0) {
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", millisLeft/(3600*1000),
                            millisLeft/(60*1000) % 60,
                            millisLeft/1000 % 60);
        textView.setText(hms); //setting the remaining time in a textView
    }
}
```

I'm invoking the method `updateTimeRemaining()` every second so that the textview gets updated every second like a timer. The problem I'm facing is seconds value always returns 0. Instead I would like the seconds value to be updated every second like below:

```
01:50:45
01:50:44
01:50:43
01:50:42...
```

Comment: Where do you assign `millisLeft` or `endTime`? Where's the timer code? Please [edit] to include a [mcve]

Comment: "seconds value always returns 0" -> your `simpleDateFormat` does not contain seconds, so those are not parsed.

Comment: @cricket007,Im passing the endTime as a paramater to the function updateTimeRemaining(). 
And I'm using timer.schedule inside a handler to make it execute every second

Comment: @njzk2, difference holds the value as Milliseconds. Isn't there anyway to calculate the HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: @Nitz what is the actual value of `endTime`? does it have seconds? Also, why are you formatting `new Date` just to parse it right after?

Comment: Why are you formatting a `Date` to a `String`, then parsing that `String` back to a `Date` for the calculation?

Comment: @cricket_007, `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting a difference between two times? It’s not what it’s meant for. It can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
difference = simpleDateFormat.parse(endTime).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
```

in place of these lines of your code:

```
String currentTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
long difference = simpleDateFormat.parse(endTime).getTime() - simpleDateFormat.parse(currentTime).getTime();
```

This should work fine.

Comment: I will check this and let you know.

Comment: If user changes phone's time then `new Date().getTime()` value also changes according to phone's time. Is there any alternate solution to this?How to get the current time independent of phone's time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**CountDownTimer**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). Here is an example :

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { // 30 seconds countdown
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

The Constructor is : `CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)`

Comment: Why that ? There is no performence issues with  countdown timer. PS:  You can also use `Handler` and `postDelayed`

Answer (score 0):

I got three suggestions.

To me the natural suggestion is you use the classes in `java.time`. They are much nicer to work with than the outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` that are built-in with your Android Java.

```
    long endMillis = LocalDateTime.parse(endTime,
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"))
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    long difference = endMillis - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The rest will be the same as in your code. To use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` on Android you will need to get [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), it contains the classes.

I wish I could tell you to use `Duration`, another one of the newer classes. However, `Duration` doesn’t seem to lend itself well to formatting. This will change with Java 9 (not tested):

```
    LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(endTime,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"));
    Duration diff = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()),
            endDateTime);
    if (! diff.isNegative()) {
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
                diff.toHoursPart(),
                diff.toMinutesPart(), 
                diff.toSecondsPart());
        textView.setText(hms); //setting the remaining time in a textView
    }
```

Isn’t that beautiful and clear?

If you don’t want the dependency on ThreeTenABP, there is of course a fix to your code. It’s even a simplification. In your code you are formatting the new `Date()` that you are getting the current time from, without seconds, so they get lost, and then parsing it again, and finally getting its milliseconds since the epoch. Skip all of that and just get the current time from `System.currentTimeMillis()` just as in the first snippet above:

```
    long difference = simpleDateFormat.parse(endTime).getTime()
                        - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

This will give you your seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a subtraction of two values and taking action if the result is greater than 0. Since it is not, it means endTime is necessarily not in the future but is before currentTime.

Fix your endTime problem.