# 30 seconds appears to be 1 hour and 30 seconds?

Tags: java, time, apache-flink

I wanted to verify my timestamps. I attached code snippet:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;   

Date date = new Date(Time.seconds(30).toMilliseconds());
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
logger.debug(Time.seconds(30).toMilliseconds() + " " + dateFormatted);
```

Turns out, the result is:

```
30000 01:00:30:000
```

EDIT:

```
   [user@hdp ~]$ date
   Thu Jun 29 11:39:27 CEST 2017
```

What have I missed? Thx!

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: Oh shoot, UTC+2!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `Europe/Paris` (purely going off your username)? It's not the same as `UTC+2`. If you were in UTC+2, it would be `02:00:30:000`.

Comment: No, I am based in Prague. [user@hdp ~]$ date
Thu Jun 29 11:39:27 CEST 2017

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, whatever the timezone is in Prague then (I'd guess the nearest olsen zone is Europe/Berlin). Still, not the same as UTC+2.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/czech-republic 
UTC +2 CEST Central European Summer Time Prague Thu, 11:42:44

Comment: CET/CEST isn't a well-defined timezone. For example, `Europe/Paris` and `Europe/Berlin` both use CET/CEST as their short abbreviations, but they don't have quite the same daylight savings rules (pre 1970, as I recall).

Comment: `ZoneId.of("Europe/Prague")` works in my Java, and yes, it gives CET/CEST (haven’t checked its historical variation).

Comment: The correct way to format a duration in milliseconds into hh:mm:ss is given in a number of answers on Stack Overflow already. See for example [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43921036/5772882). You should be able to expand the example into showing milliseconds too.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what `Time` is in your code, but I assume that `Time.seconds(30).toMilliseconds()` will return 30,000 (the number of milliseconds in 30 seconds).

You are using class `java.util.Date` in a way that it was not designed for. Class `Date` is actually a timestamp, it contains a number of milliseconds since a fixed reference point (01-01-1970, 00:00:00 GMT).

In the following line of code, you are using class `Date` to store just a time (a number of hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds):

```
Date date = new Date(Time.seconds(30).toMilliseconds());
```

Class `Date` was not designed for this and is not suitable to store just a time. What happens in the line above is that you get a `Date` object which refers to the moment 01-01-1970, 00:00:30 GMT (30 seconds after midnight on 1 January 1970 in the GMT timezone).

You then format this into a string using a `SimpleDateFormat`. Your own timezone is most likely 1 hour ahead of GMT, and `SimpleDateFormat` will use your local timezone to format the date.

If you need to store a time of day (hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds), then use class `java.time.LocalTime` instead of class `java.util.Date`. If you need to store a duration, use class `java.time.Duration`:

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(30);
```

You should be using the new `java.time` API anyway instead of the old `java.util.Date` class, because it's much better. If you are using an older Java version (older than Java 8), then [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is a good alternative.

Comment: I just needed to print out the correct duration. Library I'm using is org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` you created has the value of `January 1, 1970, 00:00:30 GMT`.
As pointed out by others, your timezone differs an hour from GMT...

Comment: It differs, by two hours.

Comment: Lemme guess, 2 hours now because of summer time (DST). 1 hour on the 1st of January 1970. Am I close? (CEST in in the console output in your question is Central European *Summer* Time and is 2 hours from GMT, correct).